# How to run my automation test on Jenkins without using the Headless when my pc is shut down with scheduler

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automation, headless

If I configure Selenium without headless in a Jenkins slave, will it run at a particular time (EXP: 2:00 AM IST)? Will it work if my laptop is shut down or VM is logged off? Also is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is shutdown, what program do you expect to actually run on it?

You would have to configure:

- your pc to wakeup at some point in time and boot up the OS
- the OS (or a timer) to trigger an unattended build of your software
- the build may or may not bring the system back to standby when done

All this is not necessarily connected to Jenkins, but it can also be achieved with Jenkins. You'd simply have to look at more than just Jenkins.